# AngularJS $location doesn't work with google.maps.event listener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I initialize a google map within a angularJS controller and add a listener to map event

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', MapMoveAround);
......
function MapMoveAround() {
    console.log($location.url());
    $location.path('/other_path');
    console.log($location.url());
}
```

The console shows the url is changed when I trigger the google map event, but I stay at the old page. If I change $location.path('/other_path') to

```
window.location.replace('/#/other_path')
```

it will go the new page, but "Back" button won't work.

Can anyone provide an AngularJS solution for it?

Comment: you need to use `$scope.$apply()` in order to run digest cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run angular code through events will not run the digest cycle, in this case you need to run it manually using `$scope.$apply()` in order to getting work your `$location` changes.

**Code**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', MapMoveAround);
......
function MapMoveAround() {
    console.log($location.url());
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      $location.path('/other_path');
    })
    console.log($location.url());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

following code also working fine for ...

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', MapMoveAround);
......
function MapMoveAround() {
  console.log($location.url());
  $timeout(function() {
    $location.path('/other_path');
  }, 500)
  console.log($location.url());
}
```